# Cohomology of a tubular neiborhood of submanifold vs cohomology of the formal neighborhood

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth complex analytic manifold. Let $Z\subset X$ be a smooth compact analytic submanifold. Let $\hat Z$ be the formal neighborhood of $Z$. Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $Z$.

> Is there any relation between $H^i(\hat Z,\mathcal{O})$ and $H^i(U, \mathcal{O})$ when $U$ is small enough? (Here $\mathcal{O}$ denotes the corresponding structure sheaf of holomorphic functions.) More precisely I would like to deduce from vanishing of one of the groups the vanishing of the other one.

I apologize that the question is vague. Thus I know that there is the notion of formal neighborhood of a submanifold in context of algebraic geometry. Here I assume that it also exists in the context of complex analytic geometry.

Remark. In my case $Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ and its normal bundle is isomorphic to the direct sum of several copies of $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: I'm sure someone will give a proper answer as I am not an expert, but I believe there are even counterexamples where X and Z are algebraic varieties (which by the comparison theorems would answer your question too). It might help to look at the 'Lefschetz conditions' and the formal duality theorem eg in Hartshorne's book on ample subvarieties